# Branch Cut Multi valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I know that the above is a multi-valued function however I am having trouble showing it. So far I have that
$f=\ln{w} $
$=\ln|r|$+i($\theta_1+\theta_2)+2\pi k$,

To satify our condition k=1. Therefore since ln|r| is constant we only have to worry about the complex part. If we trace out the path when z=0, we get arg(z)=0,arg(z+1)=0. which implies argf = 2$\pi$

Likewise when z=-2 , I get argz=$\pi$ and arg(z+1)=$\pi$. Therefore arg z=$4\pi$.

The on the full rotation we have argf =6$\pi$ since this is multiple of 2$\pi$ We arrive back to where we started so I am concluding that it is single valud. However this is not the solution in the back of the book that I am using. Can anyone please explain to me where I am going wrong